# asp.net-mvc3 Facebook Access Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-oauth

How do I get the facebook access token for getting insights.

The following is used to get the client data only, but I want the user information/fan page insight. I would like to know if I can get the insights data programatically(without logging into facebook and allowing access) with some examples in Asp.Net MVC. Logging in to facebook and granting access should also be done programmatically, I do not want the end user to be involved.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new { 
client_id     = "app_id", 
client_secret = "app_secret", 
grant_type    = "client_credentials" 
});
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```

I tried using the above as but I cannot get the insight data. Can anyone please help me. If you do not understand I would be happy to explain in detail.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new { 
client_id     = "app_id", 
client_secret = "app_secret", 
grant_type    = "client_credentials",
redirect_uri = "redirect_uri",
scope= "read_insights"
});
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```

Thank you.